# eigenvector of a symmetric matrix has $i$ and $j$ such that $x_i\ge 0$ and $x_j\le 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk

Consider a symmetric matrix $B$ with the orthonormal eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of the corresponding eigenvalues $0 = \lambda_n \le \ldots \le \lambda_1 = 1$ and $v_1= \frac{1}{\sqrt n} (1,\ldots ,1)$

Let's denote $x:=v_2$.

I need to prove that there're $i$ and $j$ such that $x_i\ge 0$ and $x_j \le 0$.

I already proved that there's an $i'$ such that $|x_{i'}| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.

This is part of a bigger proof regarding normalized adjacency matrix $A$ of a $d$-regular graph $G$, and $B = \frac{1}{2}I + \frac{1}{2}A$, so I'm not sure if more details should be added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $x\perp v_1$, we get $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=\sqrt{n}\langle x,v_1\rangle=0$. So, $x$ can neither be a positive vector nor a negative vector, i.e. it must have some non-positive entries and some non-negative entries.

Comment: In fact from nontriviality there must be at least one *strictly* positive entry and at least one *strictly* negative entry.

Comment: The fact that  you have a symmetric matrix doesn't play any role !!!

Comment: @JeanMarie Sure it does, for a nonsymmetric matrix you may not have this orthogonality property, so all eigenvectors can potentially have one sign. For example, $A=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 1 \\ 1 & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & -1 \\ -1 & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.